# A method to count the number of brackets without including what's inside the brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem using Java 1.5 that involves counting the number of brackets in a string, but also disregarding what is inside them. I've seen plenty of examples online that show how to count brackets, but I only want the *parent* brackets.

An example would be to use the following string:

```
someText[blarg[more text]and more]
```

For what I want, the resulting total would be one pair.

Comment: Regexes are not the tool for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a regex for this (not in Java, at least), but you can do something like:

```
int count = 0;

int brackets = 0;
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {  // str is the string you are searching
    if (c == '[') {
        if (brackets == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        brackets++;
    }
    else if (c == ']') {
        brackets--;
    }
}
```

At the end of this, `count` will be the number of top-level bracket pairs.

In general, regexes are not appropriate for dealing with recursive structures such as arbitrarily nested brackets. Some regex engines such as that of Perl is able to accommodate recursion, but this isn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want count the parent brackets, you can try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "[[]] [[]] [[[]]]";

    int parents = 0;
    Deque<Character> deque = new LinkedList<>();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case '[':
                deque.addLast(c);
                break;
            case ']':
                deque.removeLast();
                if (deque.isEmpty()) {
                    parents++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Parents: %d", parents);
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

The [`java.util.Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) is as last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack.

Comment: I think a `Deque` is complete overkill here. You're basically using it as a glorified counter.